# Notice: Undefined index Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation

Tags: php, mysql, sql, dreamweaver

I want a drop-box to show values of my database but can't get it to work.I'm getting

> Notice: Undefined index:.... Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation

Here is the dropbox code:

```
Fabrikat:     <br />    <select name="tillverkare_search" id="tillverkare_search">
                        <option value="" selected="selected">Välj</option>
                        <?php do {  ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $row_Fabrikat['Tillverkare']?>" <?php if (!(strcmp($row_Fabrikat['Tillverkare'], $row_Fabrikat['Tillverkare']))) ?>><?php echo $row_Fabrikat['Tillverkare']?></option>
                        <?php
                        } while ($row_Fabrikat = mysql_fetch_assoc($Fabrikat)); ?>
                        </select><br />
```

And here I defined it with recordset made in Dreamweaver:

```
mysql_select_db($database_Audiologiska, $Audiologiska);
$query_Fabrikat = "SELECT tillverkare FROM vanster_implantat";
$Fabrikat = mysql_query($query_Fabrikat, $Audiologiska) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Fabrikat = mysql_fetch_assoc($Fabrikat);
$totalRows_Fabrikat = mysql_num_rows($Fabrikat);
```

The SQL queries works correctly in phpMyAdmin so there is no problem with the SQL query.

My other drop-boxes that has the same function works fine, but I don't know why this one wont work.

Comment: `SELECT tillverkare` / `$row_Fabrikat['Tillverkare']`. Those are different -> `tillverkare` != `Tillverkare`. You need to do same case, ie.  `$row_Fabrikat['tillverkare']`

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is using a lower case column name:

```
$query_Fabrikat = "SELECT tillverkare FROM vanster_implantat";
```

But in your options you use 'Tillverkare' instead.

```
<option value="<?php echo $row_Fabrikat['Tillverkare']?>" <?php if (!(strcmp($row_Fabrikat['Tillverkare'], $row_Fabrikat['Tillverkare']))) ?>><?php echo $row_Fabrikat['Tillverkare']?></option>
```

**Solution:**

Change it to lowercase too:

```
<option value="<?php echo $row_Fabrikat['tillverkare']?>" <?php if (!(strcmp($row_Fabrikat['tillverkare'], $row_Fabrikat['tillverkare']))) ?>><?php echo $row_Fabrikat['tillverkare']?></option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not relevant, but this might help someone.

The error can also be caused by incomplete query (part of it is missing e.g $variable is empty) or by using & instead of && for AND operation. Although & might work perfectly fine in some case and not give any error at all.